# Spring Boot + Eclipse + Weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: spring, weblogic12c

I'm having an issue when I deploy a spring boot application in weblogic 12.2.1 through Eclipse Neon. This are the components

- Simple spring boot application with web dependency.
- Eclipse neon
- Weblogic 12.2.1.1 embed in eclipse

The error is:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenRequest
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:132)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:246)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

But I'm not using security in the application. If I run it as "Spring Boot App" the application runs.

I guess the problem is with weblogic, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anybody else hitting this, it appears this is a bug in Spring Boot (spring-boot-autoconfigure) induced by the Oracle WebLogic team's pesky adherence to the EE spec. See here for more info: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9441

The 1.5.5.RELEASE version of Spring Boot has this fixed. So if you're using gradle for example, changing your dependency as follows (and any other Spring Boot dependencies you have) should fix it:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.5.RELEASE"
```

I've just confirmed this works for me after getting the same problem.

Comment: how to do it with maven? i have a netflix oss based project, getting this error after deploying it in a weblogic. any idea?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Maven, but if you set that dependency for spring boot to >= 1.5.5 somewhere in your maven project it should fix it, assuming it's the same issue. Hope that helps.

Comment: tried with 1.5.5.release and 2.1.0.release, didnt work. any suggestions on debugging?

Comment: Not sure sorry, was a long time ago when I was looking at this. I would attempt to make sure that the libraries you're using are definitely the right versions that you specified - sometimes your settings can be overridden by other things in the build system - like I said, I'm not that familiar with Maven though so don't know how likely this is. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

Another guy here forced to deploy to weblogic :\

This is what I've done in order to fix the integration issue beetween weblogic, eclipse and spring-boot:

1. I've added oauth dependency to my pom:

```

````
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```
````

But after that, weblogic asked my user and password for every rest endpoint (not actuator ones)

So, here comes the second point:

2. Exclude security from autoconfiguration (or adjust it as you wish)

```

```
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {      org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class 
})
```

```
Hope it helps!

Comment: We're stuck with the same problem. What you propose is more of a workaround than a fix. While it does make the exception go away I don't understand why the extra dependency would be required at all. We're still investigating. Deploying the same application to Tomcat works fine.

Comment: Yes. It's a workaround... And Of course: deploying to tomcat works fine..but i'm afraid OPS People at my company are not very confident with open source. They sucks :P

Answer (score 1):

For me this exception disappeared when deployed the war file using the WebLogic console. Seems to be a bug in Eclipse-WebLogic integration.

Answer (score 0):

Working in 2024! Include the following dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Credit to @Bringer for providing the correct solution!